# How to use a struct/interface to mock dependency for testing

Tags: unit-testing, go

I'm new to go here... my objective is to unit test that a status is being updated in my ready().  I've been looking at https://engineering.aircto.com/writing-testable-code-in-golang/ and trying to figure out how to adapt what they're doing to my use case, filling in gaps of golang knowledge where I can.

I'm getting the error **cannot use fakeSession (type *FakeSession) as type *discordgo.Session in argument to ready** but I'm not sure *why* I'm getting this error.

**main.go**

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"

    "github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo"
)

var (
    // bot token used for this bot when connecting
    token    = os.Getenv("DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN")
    status   = os.Getenv("BOT_STATUS")
)

func main() {
    // initiate Discord bot

    // Register ready as a callback for the ready events.
    discordConnection.AddHandler(ready)

    // running the app, waiting to receive a close signal
}

// This function will be called (due to AddHandler above) when the bot receives
// the "ready" event from Discord.
func ready(session *discordgo.Session, event *discordgo.Ready) {

    // Set the playing status.
    session.UpdateStatus(0, status)
}
```

**main_test.go**

```
type FakeSession struct {
    status  string
    idle    int
}

func (f *FakeSession) UpdateStatus(idle int, game string) error {
    f.idle, f.status = idle, game
    return nil
}

func TestStatusIsUpdated(t *testing.T) {
    readyDependency := &discordgo.Ready{}
    fakeSession := &FakeSession{}

    ready(fakeSession, readyDependency)

    // @todo assert that idle/game status were set to correct values
}
```

Comment: *discordgo.Session looks to be a struct, not an interface.

Comment: @Andrew You are correct, I meant to include the link for https://godoc.org/github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo#Session.  Can you help me understand the impact of that?

Comment: @Webnet: go is statically typed, you can't substitute one concrete type for another. You might be able to replace `ready` with a function that takes an interface exposing just the methods you need, but `ready` doesn't do anything but call `UpdateStatus`, which we would hope is already tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andrew pointed out `discordgo.Session` is a go struct (from the docs link you posted `type Session struct {`)

`structs` are Concrete types in go and are unable to be substituted.  The only argument go compiler will allow for `ready` is a pointer to a session.

To break this dependency you can create a custom [interface](https://gobyexample.com/interfaces) owned and controlled by your project using the methods that you need.  This will allow you to create and call `ready` with a fake structure for your tests.

Sometimes 3rd party libraries already have interfaces so it's usually worth-while to scan their godoc to see which interfaces are available before creating your own.

---

But if you have to create your own for testing (and I find myself regularly having to do this), it might look like:

```
type StatusUpdater interface {
   UpdateStatus(int, string)
}

// This function will be called (due to AddHandler above) when the bot receives
// the "ready" event from Discord.
func ready(s StatusUpdater, event *discordgo.Ready) {

    // Set the playing status.
    s.UpdateStatus(0, status)
}
```

Now the dependency on `discordgo.Session` has been broken, and your test code can call `ready` function with its fake session, and then make assertions on it!

Comment: Thanks for the details.  When using this approach, I get the error `event.go:115:AddHandler() Invalid handler type, handler will never be called`.  Digging further it looks like it's wanting a `handler interface` which I can't find - https://github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo/blob/master/event.go#L111

Comment: And _that_ is because the author of that library has coded it in a manner that makes is nearly impossible to mock.  He accepts a function as an empty interface to AddHandler, but then matches it against a very long list of specific concrete function types (https://github.com/bwmarrin/discordgo/blob/master/eventhandlers.go#L895).  Might be worth opening a ticket on his repo and requesting he make it a bit easier to test with mocks.

Comment: AHHH didn't see the addHandler call to register `ready` :( :(